# show that $g\circ f :S_1 \to S_3$ be also smooth and $d_p(g\circ f)=(d_{f(p)}g)\circ (d_pf)$

Tags: geometry, analysis, differential-geometry, differential-topology

**proposition:**

Let $S_1$, $S_2$, $S_3$ be 3-regular surfaces and $f:S_1 \to S_2$ and $g: S_2 \to S_3$ be smooth maps. Then show that  $g\circ f :S_1 \to S_3$ be also smooth and $$d_p(g\circ f)=(d_{f(p)}g)\circ (d_pf)$$

---

My attempts:

Let assume $w\in T_p(S_1)$ be tangent vector at p of a curve $\gamma_1 $on $S_1$.

Then, $\gamma_2= f\circ \gamma_1$ is a curve on $S_2$ with tangent vector $d_pf(w)$ at $f(p)$.

So, $\gamma_3g\circ \gamma_2=g\circ f \circ \gamma_1=(g\circ f) \circ \gamma_1$ Is a curve on $S_3$ with tangent vector $d_{f(p)}g(d_pf(w))$ at $g(f(p)$.

From there, I dont know what I need to do in order to reach the Conclusion. Please show me thanks.

Comment: Hint: Move everything into Euclidean space via charts and use the chain rule.

Comment: What? Can you write more explicit ? @IsaacSolomon

Comment: There are many ways to answer this question depends on how you understand tangent space and $df$.

Comment: Hmm I define tangent space right now. @john

Comment: Let S be a regular surface and $p \in S$. A tangent vector of S at p is defined to be the velocity vector of unit speed curve $\gamma :[0,1]\to S$ in S starting from $\gamma (0)=p$. The collection of all tangent vectors of S at p is tangent plane of S at p. @john

Comment: Please help me concluding this proof. Thank you so much. You are so helpful :) Dear @John

Comment: How about $df$?